# Robotframework else if

Tags: robotframework

I am having a problem with using ELSE IF in RF. Hope you can help me.

So basically on the webpage there are tasks to be claimed, however it can happen that there are no tasks at all, or multiple tasks. To solve this, I would like to create a keyword.

```
*** Keywords ***
Claim Tasks
    ${tasks}=    Get Element Count    css:.claim
    FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    ${tasks}
        ${present}=    Run Keyword And Return Status    Element Should Be Visible    css:.claim  
        Run Keyword If   ${present}    Run Keywords    Click Element    ${ClaimTask}
        ...    AND    Click Element    ${Missing}
        ...    ELSE    Click Element    ${Continue}
    END
```

What I would like to do here, is to count the tasks, and for every task, click on the claim button, and once a clicked the claim button click on either ${Missing} and if it is not there, then click on ${Continue}.
I tried the code that I pasted, but it is not working.

Can someone help me with a solution for this issue?

Comment: You current code will always try to click on the `Missing` if the claim is present and will only click on the `Continue` if the claim is not present. You need another check after clicking `ClaimTask` to see if you should click missing or continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF ELSE problem solved:

```
*** Keywords ***
User Claims Tasks
        Click Element    ${claim}
        ${continue}=      Run Keyword And Return Status    Element Should Be Visible    ${cont}
        ${missing}=     Run Keyword And Return Status    Element Should Be Visible    ${miss}                   
        Run Keyword If    ${missing}    Click Element    ${miss}
        ...    ELSE IF    ${continue}    Click Element    ${cont}
```

Comment: You will be able to accept the answer after 24 hours. ^^